# Resolutions higher than 800x600 on nvidia (linux mint debian)

Tags: linux, debian

I have a following problem: It's impossible to set higher resolution than 800x600, on one of my screens :( the one not connected with dvi. (other screens with dvi work perfectly)

OS: Linux mint debian rolling

Graphic card: Nvidia. I have drivers to nvidia from repository.

This is my xorg.conf: http://bugari.pastebin.pl/67527

Is there a way to make screen usable? :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use `xrandr` to make a new resolution. Run the command: `cvt <your resolution>` for example:

```
% cvt 1920 1080
```

this outputs:

```
# 1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
Modeline "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

but you want just what is after the Modeline which is:

```
"1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Now open your text editor (gedit, leafpad, mousepad, etc.) and add the following lines:

```
xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
```

Then you add:

```
xrandr --addmode VGA1 1920x1080_60.00
```

Then you add:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --mode 1920x1080
```

Save this as something like `changeres.sh`

Run in terminal:

```
chmod +x /path/to/changeres.sh
```

And add the above script to your startup programs. I am using this method at the moment. If you post the resolution you want i can make the script for you.